# How to use thousand separator swift

Tags: xcode, separator

```
func showNumbers(){
    if let inputString = numberInput.text {
        let input = Int(inputString)
        let nums = input?.formattedWithSeparator
        let group = Int(round(groupslider.value))
        let priceEach = Int(round(Double((nums)!/group*100))/100)
        perperson.text = String(priceEach)
    }
}
}
extension Formatter {
static let withSeparator: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.groupingSeparator = " "
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    return formatter
}()
}

extension BinaryInteger {
var formattedWithSeparator: String {
    return Formatter.withSeparator.string(for: self) ?? ""
}
}
```

I have two places that I want to make it like 1,000,000
input String and perperson.text 
what should I use? NSNumberForatter? 
I want to use thousandSeparator or groupSeparator.
I get " Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Int' " this error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Thousand Separator to Int in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999024/adding-thousand-separator-to-int-in-swift)

Comment: it didn't work for me or I don't know how to implement that code to mine