# Remove white spaces from String after formatting

Tags: swift

I'm formatting a `String` from a `UITextField` with input type number : 
Example : If I have '10000', I format '10000' to have '10 000' `String`.

**Problem** : Later I need access to the Int value of this String, but when casting, I got an exception because the `String` is not well formatted to be casted as it contains spaces. (Example : Int("10 000") not working.)

So I want to remove spaces from the `String` before casting to `Int`, by using : `myString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)` but the spaces are still here.

I'm using the following [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999024/adding-thousand-separator-to-int-in-swift/29999137?s=1%7C39.7481#29999137) :

```
extension Formatter {
    static let withSeparator: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.groupingSeparator = " "
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return formatter
    }()
}

extension BinaryInteger {
    var formattedWithSeparator: String {
        return Formatter.withSeparator.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}
```

I also tried to retrieve the original `NSNumber` from my Formatter by doing :

```
print(Formatter.withSeparator.number(from: "10 000").intValue)
```

But result is `nil` too.

Any idea ?

Comment: because probably the `formatter` is different from the `myFormatter`, otherwise it works smoothly, and the integer value will be `10000` for the input string `"10 000"` – btw, _trimming_ trims the leading and tailing characters only.

Comment: I'm using the same from a Formatter extension

Comment: then post your _real_ code you are _actually_ using as is.

Comment: Thank you, your first answer about `trimming` shows me the way. I needed `replacingOccurences(...)`to remove spaces, stupid error

Comment: @AnthonyR `Formatter.withSeparator.number(from: "10 000")?.intValue` prints `"Optional(10000)\n"` for me. Are you sure your string doesn't contain white spaces other than the grouping separator?

Comment: I just checked, in fact yes : At the end of my `String` there was an additional space that breaked my formatter path, this is why my number formatter was not working on the strings I was using.

Comment: Please don't edit your solution into your question. Instead, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`myString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)` will remove spaces at begin and end of string, so you need to remove all spaces between characters by below code:

```
let newString = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
```

then convert `newString` to `Int`

Answer (score 1):

To remove leading and trailing whitespace:

```
let myString = "  It Is Wednesday My Dudes!   "

myString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

print(myString) //"It Is Wednesday My Dudes! "
```

To remove all whitespaces:

```
extension String {
    var whiteSpaceRemoved: String {
        replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    }
}

let myString = "  It Is Wednesday My Dudes!   "

print(myString.whiteSpaceRemoved) //"ItIsWednesdayMyDudes!"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** :

There was an additional space at the end of the strings I was using. E.g : `"10 000 "`, so the formatter path I was using was wrong.