# How to add thousand separator in type Int and Float?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a question about add thousand separator.
I have three type of number string.
I find the answer in stack [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999024/adding-thousand-separator-to-int-in-swift)
But I try to use it, and failed to add thousand separator.
Have any idea to me? Thanks.

```
let str = "1000"
let string1 = "5000.000"
let string2 = "2000.0"

let convertStr = str.formattedWithSeparator //in playground, get error 「Value of type 'String' has no member 'formattedWithSeparator'」.
let convertStr1 = Float(string1)!.formattedWithSeparator //get error too.
let convertStr2 = Float(string2)!.formattedWithSeparator //get error too.


extension Formatter {
    static let withSeparator: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.groupingSeparator = ","
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return formatter
    }()
}

extension BinaryInteger {
    var formattedWithSeparator: String {
        return Formatter.withSeparator.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Why minus my question ?

Comment: would you like to accept the answer if it solved the issue. This will help others to quickly identify the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Number formatters do not start with a "number string"; they start with a *number*. Thus, for example, using the Formatter extension code you already have:

```
let n = 5000
let s = Formatter.withSeparator.string(for: n)
// s is now "5,000"
```

But let's say what you start with really is a string. Then you could say, for example:

```
let str = "5000"
let s = Formatter.withSeparator.string(for: Float(str)!)
// s is now "5,000"
```

Observe that the decimal information is lost in this process. If that were important to you, you'd need to add that requirement to the formatter itself. You are making a string, and you have to provide all information about how you want that string to look. For example:

```
let str = "5000.00"
let f = Formatter.withSeparator
f.minimumFractionDigits = 2
let s = f.string(for: Float(str)!)
// s is now "5,000.00"
```

If you omit the `mimimumFractionDigits` info, you would get `"5,000"` again; the original appearance of the string we started with is completely unimportant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

```
func currencyMaker(price: NSNumber) -> String {

   let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
   numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
   numberFormatter.groupingSeparator = ","
   let formattedNumber = numberFormatter.string(from: price)

   return formattedNumber!
}
```

like this :

```
let myNumber1 = currencyMaker(price: 2000)
let myNumber2 = currencyMaker(price: 5983223)
```

the print is :

```
print(myNumber1) // 2,000
print(myNumber2) // 5,983,223
```