# convert number price swift

Tags: ios, swift, numbers

I have to show the price in the text of a label. public var balance: Float
only as a number I get an "8000" instead it should show "80.00 €". I can't convert it can you give me a hand?

```
public var balance: Float
    saldoPrice.text = String(userDataByCode!.balance)
```

in this way I am shown "8000"

Comment: You need to use a [NumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter) and also divide your float with 100 it seems. There are several pre-defined [styles for currencies](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/style)

Comment: You should use "Decimal" for the calculation.

Comment: You need to state your request and you can do it like this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999024/adding-thousand-separator-to-int-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following extension that solves your specific problem:

```
extension Double{
     func formatToAmount() -> String{
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.groupingSeparator = ","
        numberFormatter.groupingSize = 3
        numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = "."
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        
        let value = self.roundToDecimal(2)
        
        var res = numberFormatter.string(from: value as NSNumber)!
        if !res.contains("."){
            res += ".00"
        }else{
            let resAfterComma = String(res.split(separator: ".")[1])
            if resAfterComma.count == 1{  res += "0" }
        }
        res += " €"
        return res
    }

    func roundToDecimal(_ fractionDigits: Int) -> Double {
        let multiplier = pow(10, Double(fractionDigits))
        return Darwin.round(self * multiplier) / multiplier
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var yourNumber : Double = 80
yourNumber.formatToAmount() // prints: 80.00 €
```