# Swift automatically add "." on every 3 digit input in textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

i wanna automatically add "." on textfield for every 3 digit input, just like this as and example

[image]

how can i implement that on my textfield?

it's automatically add "." on every 3 digit num input

thanks

Comment: use `NumberFormatter`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Thousand Separator to Int in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999024/adding-thousand-separator-to-int-in-swift)

Comment: ahh okay thanks2 this question help me