# Using the split function in Swift 2

Tags: swift2

Let's say I want to split a string by an empty space. This code snippet works fine in Swift 1.x. It does not work in Swift 2 in Xcode 7 Beta 1.

```
var str = "Hello Bob"
var foo = split(str) {$0 == " "}
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
Cannot invoke 'split' with an argument list of type '(String, (_) -> _)
```

Anyone know how to call this correctly?

**Updated**: Added a note that this was for the Xcode 7 beta 1.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

`split` is a method in an extension of `CollectionType` which, as of Swift 2, `String` no longer conforms to. Fortunately there are other ways to split a `String`:

1. Use `componentsSeparatedByString`:

   ```
   "ab cd".componentsSeparatedByString(" ") // ["ab", "cd"]
   ```

   As pointed out by @dawg, this requires you `import Foundation`.
2. Instead of calling `split` on a `String`, you could use the characters of the `String`. The `characters` property returns a `String.CharacterView`, which conforms to `CollectionType`:

   ```
   " ".characters.split(" ").map(String.init) // ["", ""]
   ```
3. Make `String` conform to `CollectionType`:

   ```
   extension String : CollectionType {}

   "w,x,y,z".split(",") // ["w", "x", "y", "z"]
   ```

   Although, since Apple made a decision to remove `String`'s conformance to `CollectionType` it seems more sensible to stick with options one or two.

---

In Swift 3, in options 1 and 2 respectively:

- `componentsSeparatedByString(:)` has been renamed to `components(separatedBy:)`.
- `split(:)` has been renamed to `split(separator:)`.

Comment: It would seem that option #2 is possibly the intended replacement for the removal of `Sliceable`.

Comment: Option #1 needs `import Foundation`, no?

Comment: It's worth noting that option 1 and option 2 are not the same. For example, if the string/character you are separating by appears at the beginning of the string, option 1 will return an array with an additional empty string in index 0, where option 2 will not.

Comment: The split option generates a memory leak (in xCode8 at least). Once I replaced my split line for the componentsSerparateByString the memory leak was gone.

Comment: About your 2nd solution: You are getting a collection of *characters* and then you split them by where ever you find `" "`. I am not sure I understand the rest. So then you try to use a *String* constructor to convert to a String/human readable value? What's with the `init`? shouldn't it instead be something like `String($0)`?

Answer (score 18):

### Swift 4

```
let str = "Hello Bob"
let strSplitArray = str.split(separator: " ")
strSplitArray.first!    // "Hello"
strSplitArray.last!     // "Bob"
```

#### Xcode 7.1.1 with Swift 2.1

```
let str = "Hello Bob"
let strSplit = str.characters.split(" ")
String(strSplit.first!)
String(strSplit.last!)
```

Comment: What if the string has more than one spaces between the two words ?

Comment: @zulkarnainshah same result.

Answer (score 9):

In Swift 3 `componentsSeparatedByString` and `split` is used this way.

```
let splitArray = "Hello World".components(separatedBy: " ") // ["Hello", "World"]
```

**split**

```
let splitArray = "Hello World".characters.split(separator: " ").map(String.init) // ["Hello", "World"]
```