# I need to save an url parameter with Swift

Tags: swift, url, nsstring, nsurl, url-parameters

I have an URL like this:

```
let myURL = http://localhost/#access_token=12312312.1231231.31321
```

I need to take "12312312.1231231.31321" from that URL. I've tried with componentsSeparatedByString but I don't get what I need.

Comment: show me your code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759158/using-the-split-function-in-swift-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your question, is really just what you have mention using `componentsSeparatedByString`

```
let myURL = "http://localhost/#access_token=12312312.1231231.31321"
let strings = myURL.components(separatedBy: "=")
print(strings[1])    //strings[1] will give you the "12312312.1231231.31321"
```

`componentsSeparatedByString` will return you an array of strings that is separated by `"="` in this case.