# How to get the calories and heart rate from Health Kit Sdk in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I am creating an Fitness health app in which, I have to show user real time calories and their heart rate from Health kit. I get the permissions. But I don't know how to fetch the calories and heart rate.

Here is the permission of code.

```
static let healthKitStore = HKHealthStore()

// MARK:- Health Kit Permissions :-
static func authorizeHealthKit() {

    // HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass - For Weight

    var shareTypes = Set<HKSampleType>()
    shareTypes.insert(HKSampleType.workoutType())
    shareTypes.insert(HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate)!)
    shareTypes.insert(HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning)!)
    shareTypes.insert(HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned)!)


    var readTypes = Set<HKObjectType>()
    readTypes.insert(HKObjectType.workoutType())
    readTypes.insert(HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate)!)
    readTypes.insert(HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning)!)
    readTypes.insert(HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned)!)

    healthKitStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(shareTypes, readTypes: readTypes) { (success, error) -> Void in
        if success {
            print("success")

        } else {
            print("failure")

        }

        if let error = error {

            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

After getting success I need the calories and heart rate which function or which code I have to use. Like **Fitbit Apis** return the data or there is **Apple Api's** which will return the data?

Comment: check this - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6153

Answer (score 1):

Check this code:

```
let tHeartRate = HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate)
            let tHeartRateQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: tHeartRate!, predicate:.None, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: nil) { query, results, error in

                if results?.count > 0
                {
                    var string:String = ""
                    for result in results as! [HKQuantitySample]
                    {
                        let HeartRate = result.quantity
                        string = "\(HeartRate)"
                        print(string)
                    }
                }
}
self.healthKitStore.executeQuery(tHeartRateQuery)
```

Comment: i have to call this method after i get the permissions am i right

Comment: it will return the data like this 1.73333 count/s, 1.65 count/s, 2.48333 count/s. But heart rate should be like 98, 81, 103 in this format.

Comment: @MandeepSingh get the numerical component from the string and multiply with 60 to get the result in the format (98,103,98,etc) refer to this link to get the numerical part http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342744/swift-how-to-get-integer-from-string-and-convert-it-into-integer