# Addition operator (+) only performing concatenation instead of addition in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, operators

Apologies for the elementary question, I'm new to swift and I've been stuck at this for a while but haven't found help.

I'm trying to perform simple `math` operations like `addition`, `multiplication` and `division` etc. in my `iOS` app but haven't been able to.

When I try to `add` two `double` numbers (`weightField` and `heightField`), I get a concatenated `string` instead of a `sum`.

How do I perform simple math in swift?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var weightField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var heightField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func goButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        resultField.text = weightField.text + heightField.text
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var resultField: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var commentField: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115141/swift-converting-string-to-int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSString:

```
resultField.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: (weightField.text as NSString).doubleValue + (heightField.text as NSString).doubleValue)
```

Comment: Thanks @ Hamza Ansari, that worked a treat! I appreciate your help :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't add the values of the strings together so if you are sure that text is convertible to an `Int` you can do something like this:

```
// in Swift 1.x
resultField.text = String(weightField.text.toInt()! + heightField.text.toInt()!)

// and double values
let weight = (weightField.text as NSString).doubleValue
let height = (heightField.text as NSString).doubleValue
resultField.text = String(weight + height)
// but if it cannot parse the String the value is 0.0. (No optional value)


// in Swift 2
resultField.text = String(Int(weightField.text)! + Int(heightField.text)!)

// and you can even use a double initializer
resultField.text = String(Double(weightField.text)! + Double(heightField.text)!)
```

Comment: Thanks @ Qbyte, your solution worked well, I however forgot to mention that the numbers are Floats not Ints. Any suggestion?

Comment: Using NSString: `(textField.text as NSString).doubleValue` but if it cannot parse it the value is 0.0. (No optional value)

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I don't quite understand. Please could you explain further on how to implement NSString?

Comment: `NSString` is a class of Foundation which you can use right away since you imported UIKit already.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are concatenating the strings not number. You need to convert string into integer and then add those.

```
var a = weightField.text

var b =  heightField.text

var c = (a as! NSString).doubleValue +  (b as! NSString).doubleValue

resultField.text = String(format "%.2f",c)
```

Comment: Thanks @iAnurag, I had to do unwrap like this var a : Int = weightField.text.toInt()! + heightField.text.toInt()!  Worked well, I however forgot to mention that the numbers are Floats not Ints. Any suggestion?

Comment: I tried this approach, and I understand the logic. But for some strange reason(s), I'm getting a compile error. Not sure why. :-(