# Swift unable to parse integer from NSMutableDictionary

Tags: json, swift

I have NSDictionary with print Description as

```
{
    accStatus = 2;
    accessKey = "55d66e4d4f740-c24aa8ef3a28564db5a2bf77c8638478-712675299";
    email = "abc@yahoo.com";
    id = 15;
    imagePath = "";
    name = "Umar";
    notifStatus = 0;
    phone = 923217268138;
}
```

I am trying following code to parse

```
init (user: AnyObject)
{
    self.id         = (user["id"] as? Int) ?? 0

    self.accStatus  = (user["accStatus"]  as AnyObject? as? Int) ?? 0

    self.accessKey  = (user["accessKey"] as AnyObject? as? String) ?? "" // to get rid of null
    self.name       = (user["name"] as AnyObject? as? String) ?? "" // to get rid of null     
}
```

However its returning 0 for all ints. If i try to remove conditional ?? and replace with ! it gives me error

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x24807ac) to 'NSNumber' (0x28d96dc).
```

`AnyObject  NSMutableDictionary` clearly contains integer, how can i parse integer

Comment: maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24183839/2557145) will help you. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30897914/2557145) if you are using swift 2.0

Comment: That is not "parsing" it is just accessing values from a `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't trust `print` to reveal the types of the values in the dictionary.  Consider this example:

```
var user1: NSMutableDictionary = [
    "id1" : "1",
    "id2" : 2,
    "id3" : 3.141592654
]

for (key, value) in user1 {
    var type: String

    switch value {
    case let i as NSNumber:
        type = "NSNumber"
    case let s as NSString:
        type = "NSString"
    default:
        type = "something else"
    }

    print("\(key) is \(type)")
}
```

> id1 is NSString
>  id2 is NSNumber
>  id3 is NSNumber

```
print(user1)
```

> {
>       id1 = 1;
>       id2 = 2;
>       id3 = "3.141592654";
>  }

Note that `id1` is a `NSString` and `id2` is an `NSNumber` and neither has quotation marks `""`.  `id3` which is an `NSNumber` has quotation marks.

Because `(user["id"] as? Int)!` gives the error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x24807ac) to 'NSNumber'
>   (0x28d96dc)

the underlying type is `NSString` which will need to be converted to `Int` after conditionally casting them to `String`:

For **Swift 1.2**:

```
self.id         = (user["id"] as? String)?.toInt() ?? 0
self.accStatus  = (user["accStatus"] as? String)?.toInt() ?? 0
self.accessKey  = (user["accessKey"] as? String) ?? ""
self.name       = (user["name"] as? String) ?? ""
```

Note that `(user["id"] as? String)?.toInt() ?? 0` uses multiple features of the Swift language to prevent a crash:

1. If `"id"` is not a valid key in the `user` dictionary, `user["key"]` will return `nil`.  Casting `nil` to `String` with `as?` will return `nil`.  The *optional chain* `?` will just return `nil` instead of calling `toInt()` and finally the *nil coalescing operator* `??` will turn that into `0`.
2. If `user["id"]` is in fact another type, then `as? String` will return `nil` and that will become `0` as above.
3. If `user["id"]` is a `String` that doesn't convert to an `Int`, like `"two"`, then `toInt()` will return `nil` which `??` will convert to `0`.
4. Finally, if `user["id"]` is a `String` that converts to an `Int`, then `toInt()` will return an `Int?` (optional `Int`) that `??` will unwrap

For **Swift 2.0**:

```
self.id         = Int(user["id"] as? String ?? "") ?? 0
self.accStatus  = Int(user["accStatus"] as? String ?? "") ?? 0
```

Like above `Int(user["id"] as? String ?? "") ?? 0` uses multiple features of the Swift language to prevent a crash:

1. If `"id"` is not a valid key in the `user` dictionary, `user["key"]` will return `nil`.  Casting `nil` to `String` with `as?` will return `nil`.  The *nil coalescing operator* `??` will turn that into `""`.  `Int("")` will return `nil` which the second `??` will coalesce into `0`.
2. If `user["id"]` is another type, then `as? String` will return `nil` and that will become `0` as above.
3. If `user["id"]` is a `String` that doesn't convert to an `Int`, then `Int()` will return `nil` which `??` will convert to `0`.
4. Finally, if `user["id"]` is a `String` that converts to an `Int`, then `Int()` will return an `Int?` (optional `Int`) that `??` will unwrap.

Comment: my question actually was print description tells me its not a String then why its acting like a string note that values of id and accStatus are not in commas

Comment: Updated answer.  Short answer, you can't depend on print description to reveal the types.

Comment: Please file a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) WRT to this print issue, it causes a lot of confusion when debugging, I have–the more the better.

Answer (score 0):

`NSDictionaries` can not contain integers – they contain `NSNumbers`. You must covert the `NSNumber` to an int, it is not casting.

Use:

```
var intValue: Int32 { get }
```

or

```
var integerValue: Int { get }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4:**

```
self.id = user["id"].intValue
```

> The integer value of the string, assuming a decimal representation and skipping whitespace at the beginning of the string. This property is INT_MAX or INT_MIN on overflow. This property is 0 if the string doesn’t begin with a valid decimal text representation of a number.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414988-intvalue)