# Swift get textbox value surounded by optional()

Tags: ios, swift

My ViewController

```
/ MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var textInput: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var labelTop: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    textInput.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if (textInput != nil){
        labelTop.text = "Searching for \(textField.text)"
        textInput.enabled = false
    }                           
}
```

When I press return on the textfield the code

```
labelTop.text = "Searching for \(textField.text)"
```

is called. However the text of labelTop looks like:

> Searching for Optional("the text")

I looked at optionals (most times they use ? instead of ! right?) but do not understand how I should get the value without the surrounding 'Optional("")'

Comment: you can also use nil coalescing operator to unwrap it without the need of a if conditional brackets just use `textInput.text ?? ""`

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34294660/2303865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **unwrap** the optional value.

```
if let text = textInput?.text {
    labelTop.text = text
    textInput.enabled = false
}
```

Comment: But I thought you didn't need to unwrap implicitly unwrapped optionals  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID334

Comment: Correct, but the `text` property of `UITextField` is `Optional` as well and it's **not** `Implicity Unwrapped`. So it does need to be unwrapped.

Comment: Ah thanks I assumed there was some kind of inheritance on unwrapping