# Wont let me change label after I save it

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilabel, nsuserdefaults

I am making my own app and I save a label and saving it by clicking the player1button and I then get it back in the view did load. The problem is that after I get it back it won't let me change it again and when I try to click the goalUp button it comes up with the error: "thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION". It says this error on the first line under viewDidLoad. Please help!

```
@IBOutlet var goal: UILabel!

@IBAction func player1button(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSUserDefaults().setValue(goal.text!, forKey:"firstGoal")
}

var goal1 = 0

@IBAction func goalUp(sender: AnyObject) {
    goal1++
    goal.text = "\(goal1)"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    goal1 = Int((NSUserDefaults().objectForKey("firstGoal") as? String)!)!
    goal.text = (NSUserDefaults().objectForKey("firstGoal") as? String)
}
```

Comment: Why don't you save goal1 Integer value instead of saving the string?

Comment: Using setIntegerForKey and you can use integerForKey to read it

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setInteger:forKey:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have to do with the way you are passing `goal1` around, sometimes as an `Int` but sometimes as a `String`. Choose one and just do that. I think it will be easier to stay using it as an `Int` (make sure you save it as an `Int` as well). Anytime you want to convert the `Int` to `String` you can use `String(intValue)`.

EDIT: I just ran this succesfully

```
      var goal1String = ""
//    var goal1 = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 // goal1 = Int((NSUserDefaults().objectForKey("firstGoal") as? String)!)!
      goal1String = String(NSUserDefaults().objectForKey("firstGoal"))
      print(goal1String)
      goal.text = (NSUserDefaults().objectForKey("firstGoal") as? String)
}


   @IBOutlet var goal: UILabel!

   @IBAction func player1button(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSUserDefaults().setValue(goal.text!, forKey:"firstGoal")
   }



  @IBAction func goalUp(sender: AnyObject) {
       goal1++
       goal.text = "\(goal1)"
   }
```

Make goal1 a `String` and not an `Int`

Answer (score 0):

Try `setObject` instead of `setValue` in `player1button` method:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(goal.text!, forKey:"firstGoal")
```

**UPD**

Writing data to NSUserDefaults is not always immediate. Call `synchronize` to save it right now without delay.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(goal.text!, forKey:"firstGoal")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Comment: Check is everything ok in your casting sting to int, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115141/swift-converting-string-to-int

Comment: No need to force synchronize

Comment: The line it's crashing on has a complex mix of stuff going on. Temporarily split it out into separate pieces so you can see which is actually causing the problem. This should make it easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

`It says this error on the first line under viewDidLoad.`
Dou you main`super.viewDidLoad()`? Maybe you should check your `super`.

Comment: I meant the     goal1 = Int((NSUserDefaults().objectForKey("firstGoal") as? String)!)!