# Convert UITextField in Int or Double

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am having issue with this code, learning swift and I cannot understand why.

What I want to do is user enter on two TextField two numbers, click a Button, and then get the result on Label.

I know TextField don't allow Int, but only string and I know there is method to convert string to Int, but it is not working for me.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var firstNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultNumber: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var firstNumberConv :Int? = Int(firstNumber.text)
    var secondNumberConv :Int? = Int(secondNumber.text)
    var result = firstNumberConv + secondNumberConv

    @IBAction func resultFunction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        resultNumber.text = result

    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34294660/2303865

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29783546/2303865

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don´t put your code inside of your action

something like this

```
@IBAction func resultFunction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let firstNumberConv :Int? = Int(firstNumber.text!)
    let secondNumberConv :Int? = Int(secondNumber.text!)
    guard firstNumberConv != nil && secondNumberConv != nil else {
       return
    }
    let result = firstNumberConv! + secondNumberConv!
    resultNumber.text = String(result)

}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: I was writing the solution my own when I saw your help.Thank you very much.

Comment: I cannot figure out why I need to convert the String into Int inside an action, can you explain please?

Comment: You need to do this inside the action because is the action what you call when the button is pressed, so the event is triggered by the button.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var firstNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultNumber: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func resultFunction(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let firstNumberConv :Int? = Int(firstNumber.text!)
        let secondNumberConv :Int? = Int(secondNumber.text!)
        let result = firstNumberConv! + secondNumberConv!

        resultNumber.text =  String(result)

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I was arrived to the solution my own some minutes ago after a day! But right now I solved it practically, but I cannot figure out why put the conversion inside an action instead of outside. Can you please tell me?

Comment: Keeping it outside any function would work as a class instance member so firstNumberConv cannot get initialized with firstNumber since firstNumber itself is not available at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you **must** put the code into a function.

Second of all, be consistent!

Either you're using the numeric keyboard then go and unwrap the optionals:

```
@IBAction func resultFunction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
   let firstNumberConv = Int(firstNumber.text)!
   let secondNumberConv = Int(secondNumber.text)!
   resultNumber.text = "\(firstNumberConv + secondNumberConv)"
}
```

or you're using the standard keyboard then use optional bindings to check if the user types a non-numeric character:

```
@IBAction func resultFunction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
   if let firstNumberConv = Int(firstNumber.text), 
      let secondNumberConv = Int(secondNumber.text) {
        resultNumber.text = "\(firstNumberConv + secondNumberConv)"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you're suggest was appreciated.

Comment: Note that using a numeric keyboard doesn't mean it is safe to force-unwrap. The user can still paste non-numeric text into the text field or use an external keyboard. Or this could be on an iPad which has no numeric keypad. Never trust the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Simple misunderstanding in variable usage.
The variable "result" is estimated when the ViewController object initiated, not when "resultFunction" is called.

So you could correct this as follows

```
@IBAction func resultFunction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let firstNumberConv = Int(firstNumber.text) ?? 0
    let secondNumberConv = Int(secondNumber.text) ?? 0
    let result = firstNumberConv + secondNumberConv
    resultNumber.text = "\(result)"
}
```

And you should remove all variable definition parts. I mean this part

```
var firstNumberConv :Int? = Int(firstNumber.text)
var secondNumberConv :Int? = Int(secondNumber.text)
var result = firstNumberConv + secondNumberConv
```

Hope it could work for you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var firstNumber: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var secondNumber: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var resultButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var resultNumber: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

var firstNumberConv :Int? = Int(firstNumber.text)
var secondNumberConv :Int? = Int(secondNumber.text)
var result = firstNumberConv + secondNumberConv

@IBAction func resultFunction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    resultNumber.text = result

    }

  }
```

Put your code in viewDidLoad() method or Do this below it will be way better

```
  func updateNumber(){

  let firstNumberConv = Int(firstNumber.text!)
  let secondNumberConv = Int(secondNumber.text!)
  let result = firstNumberConv! + secondNumberConv!
  resultNumber.text = String(result!)

  }
```

then call your method

```
@IBAction func resultFunction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    updateNumber();
}
```

Alternatively if you want to convert to Double just change

```
      Int(firstNumber.text!) to Double(firstNumber.text!)
```