# How to convert a String to an Int in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get the substring of the var num, but I need that substring be an Int How can I do that?

This is my code

```
func sbs_inicio(num: String, index: Int) -> Int{
    let dato: Int = num.index(num.startIndex, offsetBy: index)
    return dato
}

var num = "20932121133222"
var value = sbs_inicio(num: num, index: 2)
print(value) //value should be 20
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Converting String to Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115141/swift-converting-string-to-int)

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You have a string. You have an index. What part of the string do you want from that index? Do you want the string from its start to that index? Do you want the string from the index to the end? Do you want just the one digit at that index?

Comment: Update your question to show the desired output from the code you posted.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Where do you extract a substring in your code? Why so complicated? What about `Int(num.prefix(2))` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `prefix` function on the characters array

```
let startString = "20932121133222"
let prefix = String(startString.characters.prefix(2))
let num = Int(prefix)
```

Prefix allows you to get the first n elements from the start of an array, so you get these, convert them back to a `String` and then convert the resulting `String` to an `Int`

Comment: I believe you can further simplify your code to `startString.prefix(2)` since Swift 4 ;)