# Why my "if" statement evaluate false even everything is correct

Tags: ios, swift

`ReferenceStringRow` is my value of text field which must be between 8 to 55. Even after providing right input, every time `else` block is executing.

[image]

```
//MARK:- Term Cheack

if matureTextField.text != "" {
    print("term is not nil")
    if ReferenceStringRow >= "8" && ReferenceStringRow <= "55"
    {
        print("values of term are in limit 8 to 55")
    }else{
        let aleartController = UIAlertController(title:"Caution", message: "Term must between 8 - 55", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let aleartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            print("Action Pressed")
        }
        aleartController.addAction(aleartAction)
        self.present(aleartController, animated: true)
        print("Values of term are not in limit 12 to 35")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ReferenceStringRow value must be converted to number before comparing it using ">=" and "<=" operators.

In this question you can find examples: [Converting String to Int with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115141/converting-string-to-int-with-swift)

Answer (score 4):

Because you treating String as number and is impossible to check with `<` and `>` operator.

you have to take `ReferenceStringRow` as Int value and compare with `Int` value.

```
let ReferenceStringRow = 34

  if ReferenceStringRow >= 8 && ReferenceStringRow <= 55 {
     print("values of term are in limit 8 to 55")
  } else {
     let aleartController = UIAlertController(title:"Caution", message: "Term must between 8 - 55", preferredStyle: .alert)
     let aleartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
        print("Action Pressed")
     }
     aleartController.addAction(aleartAction)
     self.present(aleartController, animated: true)
     print("Values of term are not in limit 12 to 35")
  }
```