# Extracting currency value from a formatted string in Swift

Tags: swift, string, currency, string-parsing

I have the following string, from which I want to remove the currency formatting and extract the numeric value for manipulation:

```
"Product Price":"\u00a3314.95",
```

I've tried using the following code:

```
let productvalue = model[indexPath.row].productPrice ?? ""
let prodval = productvalue.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u00a3", with: "")
let proqty = model[indexPath.row].quantity ?? ""

let totalprice = (Int(prodval)) * (Int(proqty))
```

However, when I run this code, I am getting the following response from an API:

> Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands

Comment: Ideally the api should return you price and currency in different fields as a part of best practice.

Comment: As a temporary provision you can use sub-string to extract numbers from string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting String to Int with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115141/converting-string-to-int-with-swift)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension that will help you remove currency symbols from the amount.

Replace your desired currency with $ for example use € instead of unicode.

```
extension String {
func removeFormatAmount() -> Double {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()

    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.currencySymbol = "$"
    formatter.decimalSeparator = ","

    return formatter.number(from: self) as Double? ?? 0
 }
}
```

How to use this extension.

```
let currencyString = "$1,000.00"
let amount = currencyString.removeFormatAmount() // 1000.0
```

Comment: here manually u r giving $ symbol but in my end there is no symbol

Comment: First, you need to Decode that Unicode then you need to use this extension in order to remove €

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the init methods you use returns an optional value so you need to include a value in case the conversion from String to Int returns nil like

```
let value = Int(someString) ?? 0
```

but in your case you are dealing with decimal values so you need to convert to Double

```
let totalprice = (Double(prodval) ?? 0.0) * (Double(proqty) ?? 0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert currency string to decimal

```
let str = "£300"

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.currencyCode = "GBP"

if let number = formatter.number(from: str) {
    let amount = number.decimalValue
    print(amount)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely the constructors of integers from string return optional values. So what you have is:

```
let totalprice = {
    let a: Int? = Int(prodval)
    let b: Int? = Int(proqty)
    return a*b // Error
}()
```

a quick fix is to force-unwrap it using `!` resulting in `let totalprice = (Int(prodval))! * (Int(proqty))!` but I would not suggest it because it may crash your app.

A but more elegant solution is to use defaults:

```
let totalprice = {
    let a: Int = Int(prodval) ?? 0
    let b: Int = Int(proqty) ?? 0
    return a*b
}()
```

But on the other hand why are you even using integers here? What if the price is not a whole number? I suggest you rather use decimal numbers to handle these cases:

```
let a = NSDecimalNumber(string: prodval)
let b = NSDecimalNumber(string: proqty)

let totalprice = a.multiplying(by: b)
```

This is now working with decimal numbers directly. To get a double value or integer value you would simply need to use it's properties `totalprice.doubleValue` or `totalprice.intValue`. But there is no need for that either. If you need to convert it back to string simply use formatters:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.currencySymbol = "$"
let finalOutput: String = formatter.string(from: totalprice)
```

There are many possible solutions to this and if possible I would try to do it all with formatters and decimal numbers. For instance in your case something like the following might do the trick:

```
private func generateFormatter(currencySymbol: String = "$", decimalSeparator: String = ".") -> NumberFormatter {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.currencySymbol = currencySymbol
    formatter.decimalSeparator = decimalSeparator
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    return formatter
}

private func parseValue(_ input: String?, formatterInfo: (currencySymbol: String, decimalSeparator: String)) -> NSNumber? {
    guard let input = input else { return nil }
    let formatter = generateFormatter(currencySymbol: formatterInfo.currencySymbol, decimalSeparator: formatterInfo.decimalSeparator)
    return formatter.number(from: input)
}

private func multiplyValues(_ values: [String?], formatterInfo: (currencySymbol: String, decimalSeparator: String)) throws -> NSNumber {
    return try values.reduce(NSDecimalNumber(value: 1.0)) { result, value in
        guard let parsedValue = parseValue(value, formatterInfo: formatterInfo) else {
            throw NSError(domain: "Parsing values", code: 400, userInfo: ["dev_message": "Could not parse a value \(value ?? "[Null value]")"])
        }
        return NSDecimalNumber(decimal: result.decimalValue).multiplying(by: NSDecimalNumber(decimal: parsedValue.decimalValue))
    }
}

let values = ["$1.2", "$1.6", "$2"]
let result = try? multiplyValues(values, formatterInfo: ("$", "."))

let parsedResult: String = {
    guard let result = try? multiplyValues(values, formatterInfo: ("$", ".")) else { return "Could not produce result" }
    return generateFormatter(currencySymbol: "$", decimalSeparator: ".").string(from: result) ?? "Could not format result"
}()

print(result ?? "No result")
print(parsedResult)
```

I hope the code speaks for itself and you can see it is easy to change/inject different formats/symbols.