# Always set "0" in UITextField if empty, even after typing something and redoing/delete

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I have 5 text fields in the ViewController that I'd like to automatically be set to number "0" after deleting written numbers.

It's default set to "0" before entering numbers from the storyboard (which is correct). But after deleting written numbers, the text field is empty. I would like it to automatically be set to "0" when empty again. And not just the placeholder, but actual number.

[Before entering numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K57bc.png)

[When entering numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFD30.png)

[After entering numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFnGN.png)

Comment: Do you want to set 0 to textfield when it is empty?

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield

Comment: Yes. It is default set to "0" before entering numbers from the storyboard (which is correct). But after deleting written numbers, the text field is empty. I would like it to automatically be reset to "0", when empty again.

Comment: You should create a custom text field to allow digits only https://stackoverflow.com/a/34294660/2303865

Comment: Note that setting the keyboard to numeric it is not enough to avoid the user to paste regular text to the text field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the view controller be the delegate of the text field, and implement the following methods:

```swift
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField.text?.isEmpty == true {
            textField.text = "0"
        }
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if textField.text?.isEmpty == true && string.isEmpty {
            textField.text = "0"
            return false
        } else if textField.text == "0" {
            textField.text = string
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

If the user deletes a text entirely, the text field will show "0".
If the user starts typing with the initial "0" value, the "0" will disappear and show the user-typed text.

Edit: To set a view controller a delegate of the text field, right click (or ctrl + click) and drag from the textfield to the view controller in the storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

and choose delegate:

[image: delegate]

If you are not using a storyboard or don't want to use it, you can always do it programmatically.

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textField.delegate = self
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time! I'm a totally noob at coding..: How do I make the view controller to be the delegate of the text field?

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly. Wish you all the best!