# XCODE/SWIFT How to get text field as integer?

Tags: swift, xcode

XCODE/SWIFT: Trying to get the input from my textfield named "numberInpt" to generate a value as an integer rather then a string. It uses a number pad if that is relevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/34294660/2303865

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting String to Int with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115141/converting-string-to-int-with-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variation on
Int(numberInpt.text)

Comment: So when I type "let nmbr = Int(numberInpt.text)" I get an error

Comment: @Reece, I'm guessing your error is that `numberInpt.text` is an optional. Check out the link Leo Dabus commented for how to handle this specific case.