# Space between characters in UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield, letter-spacing

How can I add space between characters? (hundred, thousand, million)
For example

> 550
> 5 500
> 55 500
> 555 500
> 5 555 000 etc.

I did this

```
@IBAction func textEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    if sender.text!.count > 0 && sender.text!.count % 4 == 0 && sender.text!.last! != " " {
       sender.text!.insert(" ", at:sender.text!.index(sender.text!.startIndex, offsetBy: sender.text!.count-3) )
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work properly

> 5 000
> 5 00000

then deleting with new spaces

> 5 000...0

Comment: whats the logic to add spaces? after every 3rd digit? like thousands, hundred thousands and so on

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34294660/2303865

Comment: @SandeepBhandari yes, exactly

Comment: @LeoDabus without extensions, please

Comment: You should know that spacing between digits isn’t universally done from the right, in groups of 3, or using spaces. Each of these things can differ in other languages. You should use NumberFormatter to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple ways to accomplish what you want. You can use a NumberFormatter or manually insert the spaces. First remove all non digits characters from your text field and then format or insert a space where every 3rd digit except in the first and last positions:

```
@IBAction func textEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    sender.text!.removeAll { !("0"..."9" ~= $0) }
    let text = sender.text!
    for index in text.indices.reversed() {
        if text.distance(from: text.endIndex, to: index).isMultiple(of: 3) &&
            index != text.startIndex &&
            index != text.endIndex {
            sender.text!.insert(" ", at: index)
        }
    }
    print(sender.text!)
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let tf = UITextField()
["","5","55","550","5500","55500","555500","5555000"].forEach { text in
    tf.text = text
    textEditingChanged(tf)
}
```

This will print:

> 5
> 55
> 550
> 5 500
> 55 500
> 555 500
> 5 555 000

Comment: it doesn't work right 
input: 550000
output: 5  5 0 000

Comment: sorry, input: 550000 output: 5 5 0 000