# converting String to Int failure

Tags: swift

I've two variables `number` and `number2` with `String` value, I want to convert those Strings to Int and add to each other,but the compiler returns error: `Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands`.

```
var n1 = "6"
var number = n1 + "5"
Int(number)

var n2 = "3"
var number2 = n2 + "5"
var finalNumber = Int(number2) + Int(number)
print(finalNumber)
```

I want summary of `Int` numbers and not strings. expected result: `19`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting String to Int with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115141/converting-string-to-int-with-swift)

Comment: 65 + 35 should be equal to 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because converting a `String` to an `Int` can be a failing operation, say converting `A` into an `Int`, you are using a [failable initializer](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID224).

This means that you are getting `Int?` as a result. In your first example, you get a result of `Optional(65)` **when printed**. In playgrounds, the optional's value, of just `65`, is shown instead.

The problem arrises that you can't add `Int?` together with the [`+`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/additivearithmetic/3126821) operator, only two `Int`s.

You can fix the problem by providing a default value if the conversion failed and the result is `nil`:

```
var finalNumber = Int(number2) ?? 0 + (Int(number) ?? 0)
```